# Pushing out random number in array format in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given a non-negative integer, return an array or a list of the individual digits in order.

`digitize(n)`: separate multiple digit numbers into an array.

Parameters:

```
n: number - Number to be converted
```

Return value:

```
Array<number> - Array of separated single digit integers
```

Example:

```
n            123
Return value [1,2,3]
```

Here is what I have done

```
Function digitize(n) {
  let number =[ ];
  let stringDigi = n.tostring();

  for (let i = 0, len = stringDigi.length; i < len; i++) {
    number.push (+stringDigi.charAt(i)); 
  }

  return number;
}
```

Comment: `n.tostring();` won't work, capitalization matters in programming

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For non-negative integers (0, 1, ...), you can use [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) or a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) followed by [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), use the `+` operator to turn your digit into a number:

```js
const digitize = n => `${n}`.split('').map(x => +x);

console.log(...digitize(0));
console.log(...digitize(1234));
```

Another way is to use [match(/\d/g)](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/match) to extract the digits with a regex. This method works with all numbers without modification, except for `|| []` that handles non-matches when `undefined/null` is passed in:

```js
const digitize = n => (`${n}`.match(/\d/g) || []).map(x => +x)

console.log(...digitize(0));
console.log(...digitize(1234));
console.log(...digitize(-12.34));
console.log(...digitize(undefined));
```

To make the first method work for all numbers, `null` and `undefined`, you have to add a ternary and a [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) values:

```js
const digitize =
  n => n || n === 0 ? `${n}`.split('').map(x => +x).filter(x => !isNaN(x)) : [];

console.log(...digitize(0));
console.log(...digitize(1234));
console.log(...digitize(-12.34));
console.log(...digitize(undefined));
```

If you want to use a for loop, I suggest to use `for/of`. Also take care of the case when writing `function` and `toString`:

```js
function digitize(n) {
  const number = [];
  const str = n.toString();
  for (const c of str) {
   number.push(+c); 
  }
  return number;
}

console.log(...digitize(1234));
```

Comment: The input is "non-negative integer"

Answer (score 1):

Just make it simple

```js
const fn = n => n.toString().split('').map(e => parseInt(e))

console.log(fn(123))
```

And take care of the syntax.

`function` not `Function`

`toString()` not `tostring()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
function digitize(n) {
  return (n).toString().split("");
}
```